# Preciso centralizar imagem buscada por JS e nada funciona

Tags: javascript, imagem

Seguinte, estou tentando fazer um cursinho para ajudar meu filho na escola assim ajudo ele e ainda treino um pouco de JS.
Seriam varias paginas com um pergunta e 3 escolhas
Caso ele acerte, uma imagem comemorativa aparece, caso ele erre uma imagem troll aparece. Apos seleciopnar a resposta os botoes desligam.
Ate aqui tudo bem, o problema e que a imagem sempre fica posicionada a esquerda e eu gostaria de centralizar para que fique abaixo da pergunta.
vou publicar em um servior dentro da rede domestica assim ele pode acessar do computador, meu Iphone ou de um tablet e independente do tamanho da tela a imagem estaria sempre abaixo da pergunta.
Caso fique bom e bem completo talvez ate faca upload para ajudar mais criancas com dificuldade escolar...
Segue abaixo o codigo que estou usando, agradeco qualquer ajuda

```html
<head>
<style>
#centro {
  display: table;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
</style>
<script>
    function SIM() {
        document.getElementById("NAO").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("SIM").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO2").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        var src = "https://media.tenor.com/images/b5b525642d31fc32571618da55f973e5/tenor.gif";
        show_image("https://media.tenor.com/images/b5b525642d31fc32571618da55f973e5/tenor.gif");
        var br = document.createElement("BR");
        var t = document.createTextNode("CERTO");
        var br2 = document.createElement("BR");
        var t2 = document.createTextNode("| | |3 + | | |3 = | | | | | |6");
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(br2);
        document.body.appendChild(t2);
    }
    function NAO() {
        document.getElementById("SIM").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO2").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        var src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-71kMVORNutI/VFIbY9Sh7uI/AAAAAAAAFlw/2Ix-MqWV8RU/s1600/pie_in_face.gif";
        show_image("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-71kMVORNutI/VFIbY9Sh7uI/AAAAAAAAFlw/2Ix-MqWV8RU/s1600/pie_in_face.gif");
        var br = document.createElement("BR");
        var t = document.createTextNode("O CERTO SERIA");
        var br2 = document.createElement("BR");
        var t2 = document.createTextNode("| | |3 + | | |3 = | | | | | |6");
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(br2);
        document.body.appendChild(t2);
    }
    function NAO2() {
        document.getElementById("SIM").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO2").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        var src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-71kMVORNutI/VFIbY9Sh7uI/AAAAAAAAFlw/2Ix-MqWV8RU/s1600/pie_in_face.gif";
        show_image("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-71kMVORNutI/VFIbY9Sh7uI/AAAAAAAAFlw/2Ix-MqWV8RU/s1600/pie_in_face.gif");
        var br = document.createElement("BR");
        var t = document.createTextNode("O CERTO SERIA");
        var br2 = document.createElement("BR");
        var t2 = document.createTextNode("| | |3 + | | |3 = | | | | | |6");
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(br2);
        document.body.appendChild(t2);
    }
    function show_image(src, id,) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.id = document.getElementById("centro");
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body TEXT=#C0C0C0 BGCOLOR=#000000 STYLE="background-color: #000000; color: #C0C0C0;">
<center>
<h1>Vamos Aprender???</h1>
2 X 3 =<br>
<button id="SIM" onclick="SIM();">6</button>
<button id="NAO" onclick="NAO();">8</button>
<button id="NAO2" onclick="NAO();">4</button>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca isso no css

```
img{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

```js
    function SIM() {
        document.getElementById("NAO").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("SIM").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO2").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        var src = "https://media.tenor.com/images/b5b525642d31fc32571618da55f973e5/tenor.gif";
        show_image("https://media.tenor.com/images/b5b525642d31fc32571618da55f973e5/tenor.gif");
        var br = document.createElement("BR");
        var t = document.createTextNode("CERTO");
        var br2 = document.createElement("BR");
        var t2 = document.createTextNode("| | |3 + | | |3 = | | | | | |6");
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(br2);
        document.body.appendChild(t2);
    }
    function NAO() {
        document.getElementById("SIM").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO2").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        var src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-71kMVORNutI/VFIbY9Sh7uI/AAAAAAAAFlw/2Ix-MqWV8RU/s1600/pie_in_face.gif";
        show_image("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-71kMVORNutI/VFIbY9Sh7uI/AAAAAAAAFlw/2Ix-MqWV8RU/s1600/pie_in_face.gif");
        var br = document.createElement("BR");
        var t = document.createTextNode("O CERTO SERIA");
        var br2 = document.createElement("BR");
        var t2 = document.createTextNode("| | |3 + | | |3 = | | | | | |6");
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(br2);
        document.body.appendChild(t2);
    }
    function NAO2() {
        document.getElementById("SIM").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        document.getElementById("NAO2").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        var src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-71kMVORNutI/VFIbY9Sh7uI/AAAAAAAAFlw/2Ix-MqWV8RU/s1600/pie_in_face.gif";
        show_image("http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-71kMVORNutI/VFIbY9Sh7uI/AAAAAAAAFlw/2Ix-MqWV8RU/s1600/pie_in_face.gif");
        var br = document.createElement("BR");
        var t = document.createTextNode("O CERTO SERIA");
        var br2 = document.createElement("BR");
        var t2 = document.createTextNode("| | |3 + | | |3 = | | | | | |6");
        document.body.appendChild(br);
        document.body.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(br2);
        document.body.appendChild(t2);
    }
    function show_image(src, id,) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.id = document.getElementById("centro");
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
```

```css
#centro {
  display: table;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}

img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }
```

```html
<body TEXT=#C0C0C0 BGCOLOR=#000000 STYLE="background-color: #000000; color: #C0C0C0;">
<center>
<h1>Vamos Aprender???</h1>
2 X 3 =<br>
<button id="SIM" onclick="SIM();">6</button>
<button id="NAO" onclick="NAO();">8</button>
<button id="NAO2" onclick="NAO();">4</button>
</center>
```

Comment: Coloquei e continua sempre a esquerda, na verdade ja tinha mas estava como table e nao block. Acredido que eu esteja errando na forma como chamar esse css para dentro do JS

Comment: Mas no executar está certo ou não?

Comment: Acho que deu :) precisava do centro e do img no Style e eu estava apenas usando centro e tentando chamar para dentro do JS, parece que com o img ele aplicou a todas as imagens usadas... Nem sei como agradecer, estava quebrando a cabeca a dias

Comment: Veja isso https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Resposta aceita, Duvida esclarecida de forma facil, Muito obrigado